# Scoped proxy tag not taking effect - configuration error?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I've inherited a bit of a monster system. It is a Spring framework server meant to run on Weblogic.

The code as it stands seems to work perfectly for another developer. I can clean, compile and package the project without error. However, when I try to deploy the generate .war file to my Weblogic server, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.com.example.portal.uil.delegate.ExceptionLogDelegate': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

This error points me to the following bean, which is in an external library:

```
<bean id="com.externalLibrary.ExceptionLogDelegate" class="com.externalLibrary.ExceptionLogDelegate" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
    <property name="errorLogBuffer" ref="com.externalLibrary.ErrorLogDao" />
</bean>
```

After searching around for that error for a while, it seems that it is most often experienced when the `aop:scope-proxy` tag is omitted. This bean is being loaded as such:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="foo.mypackage.SoapFaultDetailExceptionResolver">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="exceptionLogDelegate" ref="foo.mypackage.ExceptionLogDelegate"/>
</bean>
```

The strange thing is that with no files changed, this exact code works fine on my colleague's machine, so I assume I'm missing some magic configuration step.

Could anyone perhaps point me at thing to look for?

Kind Regards

Comment: Does it also work on your colleague's machine with the WAR you built on yours?

Comment: Excellent idea, I'll try that.